# Message Filters Time Sequencer not compiling - Roscpp

Tags: ros, callback, ros-indigo, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to utilize the ROS Indigo `message_filters::TimeSequencer` library to delay messages coming in from a certain topic and republishing them onto a new topic. However, my code does not compile and I get the following error: https://pastebin.com/iUavjXR2 which states that I have mismatched types for my callback.

EDIT: I have compiled this on kinetic and it seems to be working... I am trying to find out why though and will update this when I find an answer.

Below is my code

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/TwistStamped.h>
#include <message_filters/time_sequencer.h>
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>

using namespace geometry_msgs;
using namespace message_filters;

ros::Publisher pub;

void delay_cb(const TwistStampedConstPtr& delay_vel)
{
    TwistStamped new_vel;
    new_vel.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
    new_vel.twist.angular.z = delay_vel->twist.angular.z;
    new_vel.twist.linear.x = delay_vel->twist.linear.x;
    pub.publish(new_vel);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "delay_node");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    double delay_time = 1.0;
    std::string delay_topic = "/jackal_bsc/key_vel_stamped";
    std::string new_topic = "/jackal_bsc/key_vel_delay";
    n.param<std::string>("/jackal_bsc/delay_topic", delay_topic, "/jackal_bsc/key_vel_stamped");
    n.param<std::string>("/jackal_bsc/new_topic", new_topic, "/jackal_bsc/key_vel_delay");
    n.param("/jackal_bsc/delay_time", delay_time, 1.0);
    pub = n.advertise<TwistStamped>(new_topic, 10);
    message_filters::Subscriber<TwistStamped> sub(n, delay_topic, 1);
    message_filters::TimeSequencer<TwistStamped> seq(sub, ros::Duration(0.1), 
                                                      ros::Duration(0.01), 10);
    seq.registerCallback(delay_cb);
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using a constant pointer in my callback, and I've followed the ROS tutorials for `message_filters` to the T. What could be my issue?

Thanks!

Edit: I put the error in the pastebin link but at gvdhoorn's request, ill put it here:

```
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/time_sequencer.h:41:0,
                 from /home/piraka9011/catkin_ws/src/jackal_bsc/src/delay_node.cpp:4:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/simple_filter.h: In instantiation of ‘message_filters::Connection message_filters::SimpleFilter<M>::registerCallback(void (*)(P)) [with P = const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::TwistStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >&; M = geometry_msgs::TwistStamped_<std::allocator<void> >]’:
/home/piraka9011/catkin_ws/src/jackal_bsc/src/delay_node.cpp:34:34:   required from here
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/simple_filter.h:96:99: error: no matching function for call to ‘message_filters::Signal1<geometry_msgs::TwistStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >::addCallback(void (*&)(const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::TwistStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >&))’
     return Connection(boost::bind(&Signal::removeCallback, &signal_, signal_.addCallback(callback)));
                                                                                                   ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/simple_filter.h:96:99: note: candidate is:
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/simple_filter.h:41:0,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/time_sequencer.h:41,
                 from /home/piraka9011/catkin_ws/src/jackal_bsc/src/delay_node.cpp:4:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/signal1.h:91:22: note: template<class P> message_filters::Signal1<M>::CallbackHelper1Ptr message_filters::Signal1<M>::addCallback(const boost::function<void(P)>&) [with P = P; M = geometry_msgs::TwistStamped_<std::allocator<void> >]
   CallbackHelper1Ptr addCallback(const boost::function<void(P)>& callback)
                      ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/signal1.h:91:22: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/time_sequencer.h:41:0,
                 from /home/piraka9011/catkin_ws/src/jackal_bsc/src/delay_node.cpp:4:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/simple_filter.h:96:99: note:   mismatched types ‘const boost::function<void(P)>’ and ‘void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::TwistStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >&)’
     return Connection(boost::bind(&Signal::removeCallback, &signal_, signal_.addCallback(callback)));
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283432/message-filters-time-sequencer-not-compiling---roscpp/) by [piraka9011](https://answers.ros.org/users/27954/piraka9011/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2018-02-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-23**:
Please include the error message in your post. There is no reason not to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have no experience using message_filters::TimeSequencer lib.  But from your error: no matching function for call to .... we can infer that you made a mistake of using message_filters.... which is not decalied, please check the parameter type, whether it is consistent, espacially pay attention to distinguish boost and std lib. hope it will help you.

---

Originally posted by [pan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34568/pan/) with karma: 16 on 2018-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0